# How to pass multiple parameters from view to controller?

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

If function in the controller waits one parameter, works fine:

```
<a href="<?=  base_url()?>blog/edit_user/<?=$row['username']?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit user"></span></a>
```

But I need to pass $row['username'] and $post['post_id'].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to pass multiple parameter to controller use below line

```
<a href="<?=  base_url()?>blog/edit_user/<?=$row['username'].'/'.$post['post_id']; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit" title="Edit user"></span></a>
```

In your controller

```
Function edit_user($param1, $param2)
```

Comment: this solution is ok if all the data are specified. What if your first parameter is, for example, null and you only want to pass the second one? Then this scenario won't work. To be honest I do not know how to do it better, any other idea?